# Flex is not working on React Native to make calculator layout

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to learn React Native by making a Calculator app, but I can't get to work the layout in it, more exactly, the buttons are not showing with `width: '22.5%'` so it will fill the whole line, while the other properties are working.

Here is the Index.js:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Text, View, SafeAreaView, Button } from 'react-native';
import styles from './Styles';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style='auto' />
      <View style={styles.screenview}>
        <Text>0</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.touchpad}>
        <View style={styles.singleline}>
          <Button style={styles.button} title='AC' />
          <Button style={styles.button} title='CE' />
          <Button style={styles.button} title='%' />
          <Button style={styles.button} title='/' />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.singleline}>
          <Button style={styles.button} title='7' />
          <Button style={styles.button} title='8' />
          <Button style={styles.button} title='9' />
          <Button style={styles.button} title='*' />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.singleline}>
          <Button style={styles.button} title='4' />
          <Button style={styles.button} title='5' />
          <Button style={styles.button} title='6' />
          <Button style={styles.button} title='-' />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.singleline}>
          <Button style={styles.button} title='1' />
          <Button style={styles.button} title='2' />
          <Button style={styles.button} title='3' />
          <Button style={styles.button} title='+' />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.singleline}>
          <Button style={styles.button} title='0' />
          <Button style={styles.button} title='.' />
          <Button style={styles.button} title='=' />
          <Button style={styles.button} title='Settings' />
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

And here is the Style that I'm using on the app:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  screenview: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '10%'
  },
  touchpad: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: '90%',
  },
  singleline: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '100%',
    height: '22.5%',
  },
  button: {
    width: '25%',
    height: '100%',
    color: 'green',
    backgroundColor: 'purple'
  },
});

export default styles;
```

And here is the look in iPhone 13:

[image: expo screenshot from the app]

Answer (score 1):

Try styling this way

```
singleline: {
    flex: 1, // no needed
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '100%',
    height: '22.5%',
  },
  button: {
    flex: 0.25, // added
    ....
  }
```